# Which DAW can provide editing of multiple MIDI channel tracks open simultaneously?

Tags: midi, editing, track, multiple

There is already a very similar question BUT it is not the same as my question, hence the reason for my question:

[Which DAW can handle simultaneous editing of MIDI channels / instruments per tracks?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/23937/which-daw-can-handle-simultaneous-editing-of-midi-channels-instruments-per-tra)

Similar, but not the same, because that question details asks:

> edit them as one unified track

My requirement is slightly different: I would like to be able to have several separate tracks open in the same window at once and be able to edit them all while they are open, to align notes etc. This would also include drum tracks. Each track would be per MIDI channel.

In the other answer, I've seen that some apps like Logic provide for editing multiple MIDI tracks but in one edit area(1). I would not want this because of the scenario where notes from one channel overlap another and so would be hard to edit, as can't see where the note underneath starts or finishes.

I had thought Ardour did what I want but it appears not: https://community.ardour.org/book/export/html/5937

> There is no way currently to edit in note data for multiple regions at
>   the same time, so for example you cannot select notes in several
>   regions and then delete them all, nor can you copy-n-paste notes from
>   one region to another.

Can Pro Tools First or Pro Tools do it?

**Update**

(1) Changed "edit window" to "edit area" - in text marked (1) above. I still want to do everything in one Window, i.e. without opening a separate window to edit a track. I want to be able to view all the piano roll bars, separately, per track from within one window, using vertical scroll bars for the window if necessary if a lot of tracks (and scroll bars within the tracks themselves if the notes cover many octaves) AND also be able to edit directly the content in these tracks displayed. Just by clicking on the content of the track to edit it. There should be a tool bar somewhere to select which tool for editing - e.g. note lengthener/shortener, note splitter, cut paste area of track. And so, the user can just click on any track and start editing right away, they can cut or copy a section of piano notes from one track to another, or also to the same track for repeated sections.

Comment: I'm not seeing the difference between what you're asking & what the other question was asking. Many tracks, one edit window. Cubase can do this, presumably the others mentioned in those answers can do it too.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Tetsujin - does that mean that I can edit multiple tracks at once. By that I mean, for example, edit the length a note in one track and go to another an edit that. Without opening a separate window to edit. Another example: copy a section of one track and paste it into another track.

Comment: I've never seen a DAW, including pro tools, that has multiple simultaneous editing *within* MIDI clips or regions. You could go to each region, select all events, assign them to a MIDI channel for that region, give the events in each separate region their own MIDI channel, copy them all into one region, edit them in a single region editor, and then select by MIDI channel and copy them back out. You can definitely copy paste from one track to another. I'm surprised you would even ask if that's possible. Everything does that.

Comment: @Tetsujin my question is that: can I have multiple piano roll bar tracks shown at once, lined up and edit these in-place/in-situ without opening another window. In other words, I want to have multiple piano rolls tracks shown at once and be able to move my pointer over one of the tracks, edit notes in it then move the pointer to another track and edit that, without opening any other windows.

Comment: ToddWilcox as mentioned in the comment to @Tetsuijn I want to be able to see multiple piano roll bar tracks at once, lined up timing wise. Now, I know that most software does that. But I also want to be able to edit notes in those tracks directly, _without_ having to open that track in another Window. As an analogy, if one is editing a document in Word, one wouldn't have to click on a paragraph to open it in a separate editor window to edit it, and then do the same for other paragraphs.